# Нужно отнять значения числа через сет интервал

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Есть значения здоровья которые нужно отнимать со скоростью в зависимости от скорости атаки персонажа. Проблема: здоровье не отниаеться при console.log(curentChartherHealth) выводиться стартовое здоровье персонажа

```
        let curentChartherHealth
        let curentRandHealth
             let timerId = setInterval(()=> {
                curentChartherHealth = character.health - rand.damage-character.armor

             console.log(curentChartherHealth)

        },character.atackSpeed)
        let timerId2 = setInterval(()=>{
            curentRandHealth = rand.health - (character.damage-rand.armor)
    
        },rand.atackSpeed)
        if(curentChartherHealth<=0){
            alert(`${rand.name} Win!`)
            clearInterval(timerId)
        } else if(curentRandHealth<=0){
            alert(`${character.name} Win!`)
            clearInterval(timerId)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кратко то Вы не меняли character.health а в этом случае использование его в любой формуле будет давать всегда один результат. Я немного упростил код и так же вынес проверку в отдельную функцию (на мой взгляд так лучше) Обратите внимание на `-=`  так я меняю значение а не просто использую его в расчетах.

```js
character = {
    health: 100,
}

rand = {
    health: 100
}


let curentChartherHealth
let curentRandHealth

const check = () => {
    if(curentChartherHealth<=0){
        console.log(`rand Win!`)
        clearInterval(timerId)
    } else if(curentRandHealth<=0){
        console.log(`character Win!`)
        clearInterval(timerId)
    }
}

let timerId = setInterval(()=> {
    curentChartherHealth = character.health -= 1
    console.log(curentChartherHealth)
    check()
},100)

let timerId2 = setInterval(()=>{
    curentRandHealth = rand.health -= 1
    check()
},100)
```